# Google analytics - Custom dimensions

Tags: google-analytics, report, metrics, dimensions

I have been using Google Analytics (GA) for the last few years and now I am planning to use it in more detail.

I have an online quiz on a website (let's say 4 questions) and I would like to track the following for each user: clientId, nationality, Q1 response, Q2 response, Q3 response, Q4 response. I am able to pass all these as Custom dimensions, however, how do I see them in the form of a table with more than 5 dimensions? How can I export the data to excel with more than 5 columns as dimensions? Since I am looking at the data at a "user level", do I need any metrics columns at all?

Is it possible to have more than 5 dimensions in the custom report?

Also, if I have multiple quizzes, can I use the same GA tracker and somehow differentiate the quizzes? Maybe using another hit dimension called quiz name? Or do I need to have multiple tracker codes for multiple quizzes?

Thanks !

Comment: Report building is not really on topic since it's configuration, not programming (you should rather ask webmasters.stackexchange.com), but you can't have reports without metrics, and while you can't have more than 5 dimensions you can create multiple report tabs with 5 dimensions each. Send an event hit for each quiz with a different action set to Quiz name and append your custom dimensions to that to differentiate the quizzes.

Comment: You should be careful not to send personal data to Google Analytics, or you risk breaching the terms of service.

Comment: @JBrazier I am not sending any personally identifiable data(The client id (generated by GA), nationality and quiz responses)